# Exception when trying to POST using Postman to REST

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Here I am trying to use postman to provide 'form data' to an 'Rest application' but I am facing this exception below.

[Postman Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcDcM.png)<-- Check this image and imform me if I am doing anything wrong here

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet jersey threw exception
type Exception report message Servlet.init() for servlet jersey threw exception description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. 

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet jersey threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.Err[enter image description here][1]orReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M11 logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M11
```

Here is my class that is do the POST, I have taken all the arguments as strings in the 'create' method and then I have parsed them to 'double' and 'int' respectively as I needed. (If there is any other method to parse integers directly let me know).

```
        package com.glarimy.lib.rs;
        import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
        import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
        import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
        import javax.ws.rs.GET;
        import javax.ws.rs.POST;
        import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
        import javax.ws.rs.Path;
        import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
        import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
        import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
        import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
        import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

        import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

        import com.glarimy.lib.api.Book;
        import com.glarimy.lib.api.BookDAL;
        import com.glarimy.lib.db.BookDALTrans;
        import com.google.gson.Gson;

        @Path("/lib")
        public class LibraryController 
        {
            private BookDAL bookdal;
            //private String newTitle;
            public LibraryController() 
            {
                bookdal = BookDALTrans.getInstance();
            }

            //Adding a book
            @POST
            @Path("/addbook")
            @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})//Accepts only strings
            @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
            public Response create(@FormDataParam("title") String title, @FormDataParam("author") String author, 
                                   @FormDataParam("price") String price, @FormDataParam("pages") String pages)
            {
                System.out.println("hello");
                double price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
                int pages1=Integer.parseInt(pages);
                Book book=new Book(title,author,price1,pages1);
                bookdal.add(book);
                return Response.ok().entity(book).build();
            }


            //Searching for a book
            @GET
            @Path("/findbook/{isbn}")
            @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
            public Response find(@PathParam("isbn1") int isbn1) 
            {
                Book book=bookdal.find(isbn1);
                return Response.ok().entity(book).build();      
            }


            //Updating a book
            @PUT
            @Path("/updatebook/{isbn}")
            @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
            @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
            public Response update(@PathParam("isbn") int isbn, @FormParam("title") String newTitle, 
                                   @FormParam("author") String author,@FormParam("price") double price, 
                                   @FormParam("noOfPages") int pages)
            {
                Book book=bookdal.update(isbn,newTitle,author,price,pages);
                return Response.ok().entity(book).build();
            }


            //Deleting a book
            @DELETE
            @Path("/deletebook")
            public Response remove(@FormParam("isbn") int isbn) 
            {
                bookdal.delete(isbn);
                return Response.ok().build();
            }
        }

Here is my web.xml file 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>com.glarimy.lib.rs</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/glarimy/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>



This is my POM file

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.glarimy.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.40</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>mysql</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>D:\Glarimy\Programs\tomcat\webapps</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <version>4</version>
</project>
```

Comment: Seems like an authentication problem to me.

Comment: I dont think so. Before, I have used PathParams instead of FormDataParams and it worked just fine. @AdamArold

Comment: **You are mixing Jersey versions!** Please make sure your are using either `Jersey 1.*` or `Jersey 2.*`.

Comment: I have tried to change them but there are **No**  Jersey 1.* for javax.servlet and for org.glassfish.jersey.media. Similarly there are **No** Jersey 2.* versions for com.sun.jersey servlet and server @zyexal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue.
I have changed the POM file by replacing

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
 </dependency>

with

   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
   </dependency>
```

Then evereything went well as it should.